# Maintaining controls over devices

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am using two devices, Default and Mobile. I have set the layouts and the Presentation details for both devices. The issue is that when I add a sublayout to a placeholder in default view, the mobile view does not have it. This seems like how it was designed so mobile and default could be completely separate. But is there a way to make certain zones be shared between devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to fallback an entire device to another one (you can check the Fallback device in some of the /sitecore/layout/devices). Currently there is no way to fallback only components without writing custom code to do it. I suggest you either aim for responsive design and one layout or just add the presentation details to the standard values of the templates (both for default and mobile) - which is considered the best practice if you are in a common situation - so you don`t have to edit them manually on every item you create.

Comment: I think you are right. As for the custom code, I think it can be found here.
https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=45487
That post seems to be dealing with a similar issue.

Comment: @dnstommy The article you posted is dealing with a similar situation :). The problem is that you will always take the presentation details of your fallback device. In some cases that might be ineficient and you will also have no control over the order of the renderings. Also why you will need 2 separate layouts that use the same renderings :). Maybe you want to add some extra things for the mobile or you just want to have a different layout on some pages ? Otherwise there is no point of having 2 separate layouts. Also I was not certain if you are into writing custom code :)

Comment: You are right @nsgocev. We had to go another route since we would want full control over mobile and not just a mobilized version of the default. So we will have to stay within the box of Sitecore and have users create a mobile version if they like or leave it alone and let responsive handle the default layout.